Tried to setup password but elasticsearch stucks
I am trying to set up Elasticsearch on AWS EC2. It ran correctly at the beginning, but when I tried to set up the password, it got stuck. Initially, I was able to set a password using the interactive command, but then it asked for additional passwords and got stuck again. Now, the password I set is not working. When I go to this URL: http://PUBLIC-IP:9200, it runs but prompts for a username and password. In summary, I want to set up a new password, but both the interactive and automatic commands are getting stuck.
root@ip-172-31-82-211:/home/ubuntu# systemctl enable elasticsearch
Synchronizing state of elasticsearch.service with SysV service script with /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable elasticsearch
root@ip-172-31-82-211:/home/ubuntu# systemctl start elasticsearch
root@ip-172-31-82-211:/home/ubuntu# sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-09-29 19:29:45 UTC; 7min ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
   Main PID: 495 (java)
      Tasks: 50 (limit: 1130)
     Memory: 657.9M (peak: 716.2M)
        CPU: 45.646s
     CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
             ├─495 /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java -Xshare:auto -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 >
             └─998 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller

Sep 29 19:29:00 ip-172-31-82-211 systemd[1]: Starting elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch...
Sep 29 19:29:11 ip-172-31-82-211 systemd-entrypoint[495]: Sep 29, 2024 7:29:11 PM sun.util.locale.provi>
Sep 29 19:29:11 ip-172-31-82-211 systemd-entrypoint[495]: WARNING: COMPAT locale provider will be remov>
Sep 29 19:29:45 ip-172-31-82-211 systemd[1]: Started elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch.

The yml file is:
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
 # Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
http.port: 9200
transport.port: 9300
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["0.0.0.0", "52.54.229.145"]
#discovery.type: single-node
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set ofimaster-eligible nodes:
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
#
# ---------------------------------- Security ----------------------------------
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true

#                                 *** WARNING ***
#
# Elasticsearch security features are not enabled by default.
# These features are free, but require configuration changes to enable them.
# This means that users don't have to provide credentials and can get full access
# to the cluster. Network connections are also not encrypted.
#
# To protect your data, we strongly encourage you to enable the Elasticsearch security features.
# Refer to the following documentation for instructions.
#
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/configuring-stack-security.html

Health of my cluster:
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_cluster/health?pretty]",
        "header" : {
          "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_cluster/health?pretty]",
    "header" : {
      "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
    }
  },
  "status" : 401
}


Can you share the following command response?
bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
